# question about valuation ring

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

$k$ algebraically field, $A$ $k$ algebra and valuation ring of $K$ ($K$ field fraction of $A$) and we have  the transcendence degree of $K$ over $k$ is one.

i want to ask if $A$ is noetherian ring?

Comment: Please consider using more verbs, capital letters, etc. Also, just ask if $A$ is a noetherian ring. Do not ask as if that is what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is no via the following easy counterexample. Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field, and $K=\overline{k(t)}$. Let $v$ be an extension of the $t$-adic valuation to $K$, and let $A$ be the valuation ring of $v$. Then $A$ is a valuation ring of $K$ and $\operatorname{tr.deg}_k(K)=1$, but since the value group of $A$ is $\mathbf Q$, $A$ is not noetherian.